# Struct constructors and layout

Tags: c#

[Edited and expanded based on answers and comments]

We have a *public* C# API that uses nested structs without any constructors.
Note: *public* means its not ours and we need to communicate with it as given via a fixed serialization function.

Thus

```
public struct Inner {
    public int f1;
    public int f2;
    public Inner(int _f1, int _f2)
    {
      this.f1 = _f1;
      this.f2 = _f2;
    }
};

public struct Outer {
    public int z;
    public Inner f;
    public Outer (int _f1, int _f2, int _z)
    {
      this.f = new Inner(_f1, _f2);
      this.z = _z;
    }
};

public class HelloWorld
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
       Outer someVar = new Outer(4,5,6);
```

The types as given dont have the `Inner` and `Outer` constructors.

I suggested that we add constructors (something like above) since the initialization gets rather tedious. The actual structs are much larger than shown resulting in dozens of

```
someVar.f.f1 = initialzier
```

However some members of my team felt that we are 'not allowed to change the API'.

Is there any *official* position on this?
Here by *official* I am not referring to human conventions/best-practices but to C# semantics; viz. Can adding a constructor to a C# `struct` change the `struct` layout?

Also related question will a `new` or constructor on the inner struct initialize a temporary location and then copy it into the outer struct, or will it initialize it in-situ into the outer struct?

There are 2 `new` in the code above. According to the answer of @supercat below that storage-allocation may or may not be optimized away. Is there no way to guarantee that?

[Basically I am missing C's ability to make a pointer point into the inner
struct and pass it to an initializer function]

Also note that `struct` should/should not be used thus is not up of discussion. Its done thus, maybe for historical maybe for interop-with-C etc
reasons by another party with whom our code needs to interoperate.

Comment: Are you sure you are wanting to be using structs at all? It is very rare to need them in C#, pretty much the only place to use it commonly is when doing interop with native code.

Comment: There is never an "official position" on the code guidelines that a team of programmers adopts.  You can only ignore them at your own peril.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Basically I am missing C's ability to make a pointer point into the inner struct and pass it to an initializer function]

As far as I know, you can do the same thing in C#:

```
public struct Inner {
    public static void Init(out Inner value,int _f1,int _f2) {
        value.f1=_f1;
        value.f2=_f2;
    }
    public int f1;
    public int f2;
}

public struct Outer {
    public static void Init(out Outer value,int _f1,int _f2,int _z) {
        Inner.Init(out value.f,_f1,_f2);
        value.z=_z;
    }
    public int z;
    public Inner f;
}

public class HelloWorld {
    static public void Main() {
        Outer someVar;
        Outer.Init(out someVar,4,5,6);
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding about the out parameter type. Does not answer the other part about "Is it allowed keeping the API invariant". But since it answered at least half the question, Ive 'accepted' it.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you meant by *Is it allowed keeping the API invariant*. Do you mean: structure layout (fields offsets) will be the same? Structure layout controlled by `StructLayoutAttribute`. And with exception of `LayoutKind.Auto`, fields offsets are well defined not dependent of presence of methods or constructors. Anyways, if all fields are public, you can define `Init` methods anywhere. It is not necessary for them to be defined in `struct`s.

Answer (score 1):

A struct constructor is semantically equivalent to a struct member function which modifies `this`, except that the C# compiler will turn:

```
someVar = new someStructType(this, that, theOther);
```

into either:

```
var temp = default(someStructType);
temp..ctor(this, that, theOther);
someVar = temp;
```

or

```
someVar..ctor(this, that, theOther);
```

and--in the latter case--the compiler won't insist that `someVar` must be initialized before invoking its `.ctor` method (which would rather defeat the point of the constructor).

The latter is more efficient, but the compiler will only use it when it *believes* the latter will be equivalent to the former.  Note that there are some scenarios, especially involving mixed-language code, where the C# behavior will observably affect program semantics, but in most cases where behavior would be observable the compiler will use the former.

From a syntactic standpoint, a constructor call would seem most like a function that returns a structure type.  Such a function, however, would generally need to build a new structure in a temporary and then let the caller copy it to the desired location, unlike a constructor which can sometimes write directly into the new variable.

Comment: Thanks. That is at least in a useful direction. However those .ctor calls seem to be pseudocode; ie not available in C# (only IL?). I am re-editing my question to make clear the question.

Comment: There is no mechanism in C# by which code can request that a constructor be invoked via the latter approach, since it will not allow a direct call to a method called `.ctor` [with a dot as part of the actual name].  The syntax `variable = new StructType(params);` will call `.ctor` somehow, but the compiler is free to select how.  Adding parameterized constructors to a structure type will have no effect other than to allow ctor expressions which were otherwise illegal; it will not affect the layout or do other such things.

Comment: Yes, this is what I expect. But as I said we need something more 'official' -- eg msdn statement??. [And sorry but I have not the 'reputation' to upvote :-(  Even this question has two downvotes -- God-knows-why! ]